# pandas largest data return metadata style?

Tags: python, pandas

data

```
data = [
    {"content": "1", "title": "app sotre", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
    {"content": "2", "title": "app", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
    {"content": "3", "title": "pandas", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
    {"content": "12", "title": "a", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
    {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
    {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
]
```

my code

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(data)
print(pd.to_numeric(s.str.get('content'),errors='coerce').nlargest(3,keep='all'))
```

but only get, i know use nlargest,but i need more

```
[12,33,16]
```

i hope largest 3 data

```
[
    {"content": "12", "title": "a", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
    {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
    {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
]
```

Comment: Why don't you use a DataFrame instead of a Series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is working with extracted data of `Series`, so for get original data select original `Series` by [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) of index values:

```
idx = pd.to_numeric(s.str.get('content'),errors='coerce').nlargest(3,keep='all').index

print (s.loc[idx].tolist())
[{'content': '33', 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014}, 
 {'content': '16', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014},
 {'content': '12', 'title': 'a', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014}]
```

If need sorted output `Series` by index add [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
print (s.loc[idx].sort_index().tolist())
[{'content': '12', 'title': 'a', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014}, 
 {'content': '33', 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014}, 
 {'content': '16', 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014}]
```

I know requirement is `Series`, but if change it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['content'] = pd.to_numeric(df['content'], errors='coerce')
df = df.nlargest(3, 'content')
print (df)
   content   title info        time
4       33   apple       1581877014
5       16  banana       1561877014
3       12       a       1582876014

print (df.to_dict('r'))
[{'content': 33, 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014}, 
 {'content': 16, 'title': 'banana', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014}, 
 {'content': 12, 'title': 'a', 'info': '', 'time': 1582876014}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will consider the dataframe

Comment: @ezrael if use dataFrame  change data type
use dataFrame 
{'content': 33, 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014},
but i need data is
{'content': '33', 'title': 'apple', 'info': '', 'time': 1581877014},

Comment: @xin.chen - agree, data are changed and also non numeric strings are converted to `NaN`s.

Comment: @xin.chen - If no `bad data` is possible convert numbers to strings before `to_dict()` by `df['content'] = df['content'].astype(str)`

Comment: has new question content type is int,change float  ,my code 
```df = self.df.nlargest(3, 'content')```
```df['content'] = df['content'].astype(str)```
data is 
```{'content': '66.0', 'title': 'appstore', 'info': '', 'time': 1561877014},```

Comment: @xin.chen - Problem is some missing values - so integers are converted to floats. Possible solution is `df['content'] = df['content'].astype('Int64').astype(str)` - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Comment: @xin.chen - Yop, understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a DataFrame instead of a Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['content'] = pd.to_numeric(df['content'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df.iloc[df['content'].nlargest(3).index]
```